# Autogenerate .proto files in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a flutter app with a client which sends data to a server. For this I convert my data to json. At a certain point this data will need to be saved to disk as well. Someone pointed out that it would be good to use grpc for this. After reading about it I found out that there are some good benifits, thus I want to start using it.

Now I have the following problems:

1: I need to convert all my model classes to .proto files manually.

2: My model classes contain some properties. I dont see that I can place properties in the .proto files.

Question 1: Is there a way of automatically converting classes to .proto files which I am missing?

Question 2: Is there a way to place properties in my .proto files or am I thinking wrong?

I was only able to find two packages for helping with converting to proto files 'proto_generator' and 'proto_annotations', but these are not from google and thus I prefer not to use them.

Comment: If you have a working app that uses HTTP|JSON, I'd encourage you to give considerable thought to breaking your app in order to reap the (valid) benefits of gRPC. If you're unfamiliar with gRPC and protocol buffers, you will need to do the work to reconfigure your app to support gRPC and protocol buffers **and** you will need to learn new tools and mechanisms for debugging these technologies. Doing this may take away from your ability to enhance the end-user experience of your app for the (dubious?) benefits of improving its plumbing.

Comment: I'm less familiar with Dart and its tooling but Google|gRPC|Protobufs don't have extensive tooling to go from language-speciifc implementations to the language-independent protocol buffers. I think there are 2 reasons for this. First, language-specific implementations may encourage a language-specific schema when it may be preferable to start with the generic "What methods and messages should my app's components exchange?". Second, you should generally **not** bind your application data model to the on-the-wire model. There should **not** be a 1:1 correspondence between the two.

Comment: Thanks DazWilkin for your second answer. If you place this as an answer I can mark it as answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm less familiar with Dart and its tooling but Google|gRPC|Protobufs don't have extensive tooling to go from language-specific implementations to the language-independent protocol buffers.

I think there are 2 reasons for this:

First, language-specific implementations may encourage a language-specific schema when it may be preferable to start with the generic "What methods and messages should my app's components exchange?";

Second, you should generally not bind your application data model to the on-the-wire model. There should not be a 1:1 correspondence between the two.